# mySQL Query 2 Tables Left Join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 2 tables - User and Result

```
ID | UserID | League
1  | 123    | Great
2  | 124    | Great  
3  | 125    | Great  
4  | 123    | Ultra  
5  | 124    | Ultra  
6  | 126    | Ultra  

ID | Winner | Loser | League
1  | 124    | 123   | Great
2  | 124    | 123   | Ultra
3  | 124    | 125   | Great
```

I want to select all the distinct UserIDs that have not done a specific League before with a certain user if they have that League in User table.

So if I was to do it for 126 Ultra, it should return - 123,124
And for 123 Great - 125

So far I have

`` SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM `User` t1 LEFT JOIN `Result` t2 ON (t1.UserID = t2.Winner OR t1.UserID = t2.Loser) WHERE UserID != 125 AND t1.League = 'Ultra' AND t2.id IS NULL ``

I'm not sure what I'm missing, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Server version: 10.3.12-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

Comment: Why would you get  `Great -125`  when you input `123`? could you explain more detail?

Comment: If selected 123 for UserID and Great for League, only 125 should be the outcome as 123 has already done Great with 124, and 126 just has Ultra, no great in User table, and it can't select itself (123), therefore just leaving 125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the results you want, you need to get a list of all the users in the league of interest (excluding the user you are searching on) and then `LEFT JOIN` that to the `Result` table, selecting only rows with no matching result. That will then give you the list of users that a particular users has not played in that league. In MariaDB 10.3, that can be done with a CTE (this example is for user `123 Great`):

```
WITH Users AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT UserID 
   FROM User
   WHERE League = 'Great' AND UserID != 123)
SELECT UserID
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Result r ON r.League = 'Great'
                  AND ((r.Winner = u.UserID AND r.Loser = 123)
                    OR (r.Winner = 123 AND r.Loser = u.UserID)
                      )
WHERE r.ID IS NULL
```

Output:

```
UserID
125
```

Demo (includes results for `126 Ultra`) on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4c366f653e14390e29cfd4c88f7e0d78)